# How to revert back to PyTorch 1.4?

Tags: pytorch

I have had PyTorch 1.4 installed on my machine for a little while now, and just tried to install 1.5 using the directions found directly on PyTorch.org.

Unfortunately, it failed, as do most things I try to do exactly as told. No shocker there.

Now, I have some half-installation of PyTorch 1.5 that will not import, but insists that it's on my machine. It fails with a `FileNotFoundError`, referring specifically to `caffe2_nvrtc.dll`.

I found an issue on GitHub with this problem that was closed last month, but of course it still is an issue, and many other people have reported it since it was closed. There has been no real resolution.

I just want to go back. What is the best way of getting rid of 1.5 without screwing up my machine and its environments even worse? And then, where do I find v1.4? It is not listed on the "Previous PyTorch Versions" page.

Comment: You can just download the wheel file of the pytorch and install it using pip

Answer (score 0):

The old versions are still available as before and you can install them directly with pip by specifying the version you want to install:

```
pip install torch==1.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

As you seem to be on Windows the `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` part is required, because the Windows versions are not distributed over PyPI, but you have get them from PyTorch's registry. There you can also find all the versions (including past versions) of PyTorch.

Installing an older version of the same package should remove the current one, but in case you run into problems with that, you can first uninstall PyTorch before you install the older version:

```
pip uninstall torch
```